# How to Join Games with Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.7

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't find how to join games with the latest 0.7 Pocket Edition update with an iPad and iPod over wifi. I see the realm options but I get the message "there are no more open server slots right now". Local server multiplayer is switched on for both devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no button for it anymore. Local games that have the local server option turned on automatically show up in the Worlds list of other players.

One of you should start up a world while the other stays on their Worlds list (the menu you see after pressing <kbd>Play</kbd>) and waits for it to appear at the bottom of the list. It should be blue in the list.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. The ipod is running on an older ios, maybe it's a mis-match issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work between 2 iPhone 5's and an iPad 3.  The local server game is down at the bottom of the list, after all of the really old games.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hit play and scroll down to the bottom of the list. There will be a world that is the name of the person you are joining in blue letters. Click it to join.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to play with someone sitting right next to you press the play button because if you are trying to play online you need to buy the app.