# What is Realms and why does it keep telling me "No available servers"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I visit worlds on the 0.7.1 version of Minecraft PE?

I signed up for Realms and so did my friend and I want her to visit my world there but it says there is no available servers. What is Realms anyway – is it the new way to connect servers? Do we need to be on the same wifi system anymore?

Comment: Do you mean pocket edition?

Answer (score 2):

The answers are mostly in the screen that the Realms button shows you (emphasis mine):

> Welcome to Minecraft Realms **Beta**!
>   We're still testing out features, but
>   eventually **Realms will let up to 10 Pocket
>
>   Edition users play together online**. It's
>   currently free, and **limited to a set
>
>   amount of servers**.

So Realms is a way of playing multiplayer with other players over the Internet – using a Realms server, you don't need to be on the same wifi network. To make that work, Mojang has to run servers, but since this is in beta now, there are a limited number of servers. When it says "No available servers", that's PE telling you that all of the Realms Beta servers are already being used by other PE players.

[The way you join a local multiplayer world has changed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/how-to-join-games-with-minecraft-pocket-edition-0-7), but you can still play multiplayer on local wifi. That's good, because Realms will be for-pay once it's out of beta.