# What is Realms and why can't I connect to it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What does "Play On Realms" mean? Does it need an Internet connection?

How can we play Realms? It asked me to sign up but when I did it said "Unable To Connect World."

Answer (score 0):

"What is Minecraft Realms?" is mostly answered already [on this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120612/what-is-realms-and-why-does-it-keep-telling-me-no-available-servers), but you seem to have problems that go beyond that question.

Yes, Realms requires an Internet connection. It's a set of servers run by Mojang to let people play together without having to be on the *same* wifi connection, but it still requires wifi and an Internet connection.